# Oracle APEX in browser over VPN

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

After lots of futzing around with all of the settings, I finally managed to get APEX to work on a remote server. To get that to happen, I had to grant my user the SYSDBA role, and I also included myself in the ORADBA group on that machine. I can log in to APEX at `http://computername:8085/apex`. (Note that I used port 8085 instead of 8080 - there seemed to be an Apache listener using 8080).

My question is, how do I connect to APEX without using the remote desktop. That is, VPNing to the machine, and just opening the browser on my local computer and typing `http://computername:8085/apex`. I've looked all over and tried numerous approaches, including

EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);

Any ideas?

Comment: This is more a network question than a programming question. You should have better answers over at serverfault. Basically if you can connect via browser on the same machine, you should be able to connect by browser on **any** machine on the same network (except firewall rules of course).

Comment: Ah, I didn't even know that serverfault existed! Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes looking for this: I had to open up port 8085 (the port that I chose; by default it's 8080, but I had a listener there already) on the local computer's firewall (where Oracle & APEX are installed) to both incoming and outgoing connections. For me, this was as easy as opening up Windows firewall, going to advanced settings, and adding a rule for this port to both the inbound and outbound rules section.